# UICollectionView doesn't update all cells properly via cellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following setup: a `UICollectionView` with a custom cell, where the user can select multiple cells and then perform some heavy image operation. Now I try to update the selected cells which the user selected with the result of that operation, which will be produced by a function of the subclassed custom cell. For all visible cells, the function is called on button press by the user and for all other cells, this happens via `cellForItemAt` in order to be most efficient.

However, I face the problem now, that the visible cells are all updated but then after scrolling the cells right behind or before the visible cells **do not get updated** via `cellForItemAt` but only when scrolling forth and back. Please see the attached video.

For demonstration purposes I just show a green `UIView` for the image operation. Because that operation is resource heavy, **I cannot use any of the `UICollectionView` reloadData** or similar, as they would deselect the selected cells, and manual re-selection will cause flickering.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // data source
    var items: [String] = ["Lynna", "Vickie", "Emmerich", "Chere", "Patrizius", "Micky", "Sarena", "Jewell", "Audrye", "Rockwell", "Lari", "Travis", "Ber", "Oneida", "Bethanne", "Geri", "Gray", "Wolfie", "Hallsy", "Vanna", "Aline", "Winslow", "Amelita", "Janek", "Samuel", "Jaclin", "Dick", "Jeanine", "Brandy", "Munroe", "Felice", "Melonie", "Esta", "Bria", "Kenon", "Roarke", "Gerry", "Carmel", "Conrado", "Jaquelin", "Avrit", "Noam", "Kleon", "Edith", "Carine", "Jackie", "Franni", "Riccardo", "Theda", "Virgina", "Carleen", "Gregorio", "Taylor", "Ellsworth", "Adolphus", "Annabella", "Natalya", "Celina", "Cathrine", "Evie", "Gasper", "Aguste", "Jory", "Farrell", "Natasha", "Deborah", "Pietro", "Lucila", "Yuri", "Micheil", "Claus", "Nelson", "Elisa", "Alfons", "Nicolea", "Sofia", "Geordie", "Anette", "Myrtice", "Tami", "Lucien", "Brigida", "Claire", "Brennan", "Kendal", "Jillana", "Adelaida", "Charles", "Mart", "Hastie", "Dewain", "Heida", "Karisa", "Arleyne", "Margi", "Brent", "Natalie", "Ashton", "Teodorico", "Prentice", "Rolando", "Tootsie", "Fonz", "Tremayne", "Bernardo", "Guthrie", "Hendrick", "Constantina", "Lin", "Reece", "Horace", "Celka", "Amata", "Dunc", "Franchot", "Niko", "Janna", "Jacklyn", "Eddy", "Ashely", "Angelica", "Pinchas", "Krishnah", "Edmon", "Darnell", "Alyson", "Pearle", "Ashla", "Chickie", "Ada", "Elane", "Bethanne-Two", "Lon", "Marlin", "Karissa", "Ellswerth", "Lisbeth", "Cortie", "Lucille", "Lissa", "Markos", "Alys", "Orrin", "Nancy", "Pepe", "Lauren", "Wyndham", "Belle", "Gordie", "Marcille", "Idaline", "Hillary", "Enrique", "Murielle", "Juliann", "Beatrisa", "Lavinia", "Noni", "Justino", "Hasty", "Sile", "Kiley", "Shepard", "Nickie", "Ly", "Dannel", "Tressa", "Merci", "Rog", "Frans", "Bernita", "Ginnie", "Niko-Two", "Sheilakathryn", "Whitman", "Kendell", "Florenza", "Marybeth", "Drusi", "Paulina", "Fina", "Moria", "Jacobo", "Rowan", "Mariejeanne", "Luelle", "Vicki", "Auria", "Trisha", "Ken", "Carline", "Dorry", "Forrester", "Wylie", "Elset", "Francyne", "Bondy", "Demott", "Erik", "Elenore", "Correy", "Isadora", "Mason", "Barris", "Marlee", "Haslett", "Lorette", "Arlyn", "Genna", "Trude", "Parnell", "Albina", "Spencer", "Lefty", "Luigi", "Winnie", "Torie", "Zita", "Bert", "Danyelle", "Aldis", "Rivy", "Niels", "Monte", "Sandy", "Georgeta", "Durante", "Cobbie", "Kathryn", "Dinnie", "Fanchon", "Say", "Ethelred", "Vick", "Betteanne", "Orazio", "Mannie", "Jinny", "Kerrin", "Abagail", "Reyna", "Tomlin", "Shelton", "Noble", "Massimiliano", "Madel", "Cayla", "Mathias", "Tod", "Liana", "Celia", "Antoni", "Ruthann", "Irvine", "Leisha", "Geri-Two", "Marlie", "Pascale", "Latia", "Minne", "Arlette", "Rhys", "Flint", "Sollie", "Hinda", "Igor", "Marcella", "Wilma", "Marijo", "Marika", "Pooh", "Roland", "Sergent", "Fawnia", "Valaree", "Evonne", "Angeline", "Welbie", "Mace", "Niles", "Grannie", "Berenice", "L;urette", "Nert", "Rheba", "Cristie", "Lazar", "Amil", "Yanaton", "Luella", "Herold", "Enrique-Two", "Joanna", "Dom", "Crista", "Ellyn", "Ema", "Romona", "Dona", "Madelina", "Nevsa", "Conway", "Laverna", "Orion", "Leighton", "Earle"]

    // stores the selected items
    var selectedItems = [String]()

    var applyImageOperation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set up collection view
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        self.collectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSelectAllPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Add all items to the seleted array
        selectedItems = [String]() // empty the current selection first
        for item in items {
            selectedItems.append(item)
        }

        // Update the collection view visually by selecting all cells
        for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnApplyImageOperationPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // set image operation mode true if we have items selected
        if selectedItems.count > 0 {
            applyImageOperation = true
        }

        // All visible cells should call activateImageOperationMode() - all others will do in cellForItem
        for visibleCell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let cell = visibleCell as? MyCustomCell {
                if let name = cell.titleLabel.text {
                    if selectedItems.contains(name) {
                        cell.activateImageOperationMode()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: ((collectionView.frame.width-12)/3), height: ((collectionView.frame.width-12)/3))
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CELL", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]

        // if image operation is not active, we don't show / remove the view
        if !applyImageOperation {
            cell.deactivateImageOperationMode()
        }
        // if image operation is active, we show the view for all selected items
        else {
            // Check if cell is selected
            if selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) {
                cell.activateImageOperationMode()
            }
            // If cell is not selected
            else {
                cell.deactivateImageOperationMode()
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Add item to selectedItems
        if !selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedItems.append(items[indexPath.row])
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Remove item from selectedItems
        if selectedItems.contains(items[indexPath.row]) {
            selectedItems.removeAll{ $0 == items[indexPath.row] }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCustomCell**

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = "n/a"
        l.textColor = .red
        l.textAlignment = .center
        return l
    }()

    let bgColor: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return v
    }()

    var myImageOperationView: UIView?



    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        // Configure Selection Background View
        selectedBackgroundView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return view
        }()

        // Set std BG color
        contentView.addSubview(bgColor)
        bgColor.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
        bgColor.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
        bgColor.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
        bgColor.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true

        // Setup label
        bgColor.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    func activateImageOperationMode() {
        if myImageOperationView == nil {
            // HERE WOULD BE SOME HEAVY IMAGE OPERATION
            // Adding this view is just a placeholder for demonstration
            myImageOperationView = UIView()
            myImageOperationView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            myImageOperationView!.backgroundColor = .green
            bgColor.addSubview(myImageOperationView!)
            myImageOperationView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            myImageOperationView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            myImageOperationView!.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            myImageOperationView!.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgColor.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            // bring label to top
            bgColor.bringSubviewToFront(titleLabel)
        }
    }

    func deactivateImageOperationMode() {
        if myImageOperationView != nil {
            myImageOperationView!.removeFromSuperview()
            myImageOperationView = nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Video showing the behavior**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionView defaults to [`prefetchingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1771771-prefetchingenabled) == `YES`, which means that the collection view will request cells before it needs to display them. If the app's state changes such that the cells that have already been fetched need to be displayed differently, you can implement the [`collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc) method to update the cell.

It looks like this is exactly your problem... you turn on a feature that should change the way the cells look, but the cells that have been fetched but which aren't visible don't get updated. Implementing `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` should solve the problem.

Comment: Would that mean the whole implementation from `cellForItemAt` goes into `willDisplayCell` or just parts of it?

Comment: @Pauli That depends on what you need to do. If the data in the cell stays the same but the appearance changes, as in your case, you could just change that. If you really need to do the same thing that you do in `cellForItemAt:` then you could factor that common code out into a separate method. Or, it might be better to just turn off prefetching.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Here is also some useful information: https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/241-uicollectionview-cell-pre-fetching